# How to make a counter based on other columns within the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a large dataframe that contains multiple kids' exact age and gender, along with some unrelated binary columns, as follows:

```
       kid1_age    kid2_age    kid3_age   kid1_gndr  kid1_gndr    kid2_gndr ..  age_1825   age_1217  ..
 index
   0      18           12         nan       Male       Male          nan           1          1 
   1      21           17         nan       Female     Male          nan           1          0 
   2      15           13          1        Female     Female        Male          0          1
```

Where age_1825 means it refers to the kids aged 18 - 25 y.o.,age_1217 means kids aged 12 - 17 y.o. etc.

The "TRUE" value in these binary columns means the kid in that age range filled in the data correctly.

The number of columns is far higher than this, and the binary columns would cover each age range possible. But this is the gist of my dataframe.

My goal is to make a **column of counter for Gender of each kid that fills in correctly (as defined by the binary columns and the age range in their names)**. For example, for the data above, based on the binary columns that I compare with the kids' age and gender, I should get:

```
kid1_age  kid2_age   kid3_age  kid1_gndr  kid1_gndr  kid2_gndr  age_1825  age_1217      Male      Female

18           12       nan       Male       Male        nan         1         1           2          0
21           17       nan       Female     Male        nan         1         0           0          1
15           13       1         Female     Female      Male        0         1           0          2
```

To clarify: **The counter isn't for the gender of the kids, but the gender of the kids that are marked as 1 in the binary column, as constrained by the age group**.

The counter then needs to:

1. identify the age group of the kid that fills in correctly (i.e. 18 - 25 y.o. and 12 - 17 y.o. on the first row)
2. identify which kid this might possibly refer to (i.e. kid1 and kid2 respectively)
3. identify what gender kid1 and kid2 are based on the kid1_gndr and kid2_gndr columns
4. Add the gender to the counter.

I'm quite new in Python and I am clueless on how to do this properly... any help or clues would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It would help people people to answer your question if you provide [a good, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) of your input and expected output. A good example is much more concise and informative than a long description. The downvotes (not mine btw!) are most likely because of that.

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the `_gndr` columns, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and compute a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df.filter(like='_gndr').stack().droplevel(1)
cols = s.unique()
df[cols] = pd.crosstab(s.index, s)[cols]
```

Or with [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.filter(like='_gndr').stack().droplevel(1)

df = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```

Output:

```
       kid1_age  kid2_age  kid3_age kid1_gndr kid2_gndr kid3_gndr  age_1825  age_1217  Female  Male
index                                                                                              
0            18        12       NaN      Male      Male       NaN         1         1       0     2
1            21        17       NaN    Female      Male       NaN         1         0       1     1
2            15        13       1.0    Female    Female      Male         0         1       2     1
```

Comment: Where is tested ranges? Answer is wrong

Comment: check expected ouput

Comment: Then the question is unclear, there is no link between a particular kid and a range

Comment: maybe missing age_1017 column filled three times 0

Comment: I might have an idea, but OP should clarify in any case

Comment: yop, or maybe is necesary test each age_ column by all kid_ columns

Comment: testing each age_ column by all kid_columns is correct. Apologies for the ambiguous line of questioning, I have clarified the goal of the question and the necessary steps in the body text.